# Windows Azure Service Bus Queues: Throttling and TOPAZ

Tags: azure, enterprise-library

Today at a customer we analysed the logs of the previous weeks and we found the following issue regarding Windows Azure Service Bus Queues:

> The request was terminated because the entity is being throttled.
>   Please wait 10 seconds and try again.

After verifying the code I told them to use the Transient Fault Handing Application Block (TOPAZ) to implement a retry policy like this one:

```
 var retryStrategy = new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
 var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);
```

The customer answered:

> "Ah that's great, so it will also handle the fact that it should wait
>   for 10 seconds when throttled."

Come to think about it, I never verified if this was the case or not. I always assumed this was the case. In the **Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling** assembly I looked for code that would wait for 10 seconds in case of throttling but didn't find anything.

Does this mean that TOPAZ isn't sufficient to create resilient applications? Should this be combined with some custom code to handle throttling (ie: wait 10 seconds in case of a specific exception)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall, the "10 second" wait isn't a requirement. Additionally, TOPAZ I believe also has backoff capabilities which would help you over come thing.

On a personal note, I'd argue that simply utilzing something like TOPAZ is not sufficient to creating a truely resilient solution. Resiliency goes beyond just throttling on a single connection point, you'll also need to be able to handle failover to a redundant endpoint which TOPAZ won't do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as throttling concerned, [Topaz](http://aka.ms/topaz) provides a set of built-in retry strategies, including:
 - Fixed interval
 - Incremental intervals
 - Random exponential back-off intervals

You can also write your custom retry stragey and plug-it into Topaz.

Also, as Brent indicated, 10 sec wait is not mandatory. In many cases, retrying immediately may succeed without the need to wait. By default, Topaz performs the first retry immediately before using the retry intervals defined by the strategy.

For more info, see [Ch.6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680901%28PandP.50%29.aspx) of the "Building Elastic and Resilient Cloud Apps" Developer's Guide, also available as epub/mobi/pdf from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=234700).

If you have suggestions/feature requests for Topaz, please submit them via the [uservoice](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/101257-windows-azure-integration-pack/).